# docker-entrypoint.sh permission denied

Tags: docker, permissions

I am trying to create a Docker container but I have reached a point where any container I start automatically exits with the message:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 11: .: Permission denied
```

This is roughly how I got to this point: I first followed the Docker Desktop tutorial on https://www.docker.com/101-tutorial/ . This worked fine at first so I moved on to creating a container in the React repo I am working on. I had to create a .dockerignore file to exclude node modules and this caused a fatal error in Docker, so I reset it to factory settings (that was the only option). From that moment on, launching any container automatically results in the error above. This includes the container created in the tutorial (in other words: the tutorial worked at first, but now it has stopped working). The file docker-entrypoint.sh does not exist anywhere on my system (I'm assuming it is automatically created by Docker inside the container's file system?). I have tried adding the following command to my dockerfile:

```
RUN chmod a+rwx .
```

... or:

```
RUN chmod 755 .
```

... to attempt to force the permissions within the container's file system, but it did not help.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Docker Desktop, but this did not work. I have also tried this with the latest Docker Desktop version, but I still get the same error. I am on Windows 11 Home.

Does anyone know what the issue could be? Please note that there are many questions on StackOverflow about the same error message, but I have checked and none of them solve my issue. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Describing what you've done is helpful, but can we see the actual Dockerfile and what you're actually doing to build the image and run the container?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I wasn't sure what example to add because I was following the tutorial I linked. But I've just found the solution (was making a very simple mistake, see below), so it's all working now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I've been going over the commands I was using and it turns out I was making a very simple mistake. The command I was running to start my containers (for example the container from the tutorial) was:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 getting-started .
```

... where it should have been:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 getting-started
```

In other words, I added a period at the end that shouldn't have been there.